# Finite collection of continuous functions is equicontinuous.

Tags: general-topology, equicontinuity

**Definition:** Let $F \subseteq C(X,Y)$ where $X$ is a topological space, $(Y,d)$ a metric space. Then $F$ is called equicontinuous in $x$ iff

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists V \in \mathcal{V}(x): \forall f \in F: f(V) \subseteq B_d(f(x), \epsilon)$$

> Let $F = \{f_1, \dots, f_n\} \subseteq C(X,Y)$ be a finite collection
>   of continuous functions where $X$ is an arbitrary topological space
>   and $(Y,d)$ is a metric space. Prove that $F$ is equicontinuous.

**Attempt:**

Let $x \in X$ be fixed, $\epsilon > 0$. Put $V:= \bigcap_{j=1}^n f_j^{-1}(B_d(f(x), \epsilon))$. Then $V$ is a nbh of $x$, as $f_i$ is continuous and finite intersections of nbh's are nbh's.

Then, if $i \in \{1, \dots n\}$, it follows that $f_i(V) \subseteq B_d(f_i(x), \epsilon)$

Hence, $F$ is equicontinuous in $x$, and since $x$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

My problem with this solution is that $V$ seems to depend on $F$, and this isn't allowed. Any comments on this?

Comment: $V$ is allowed to depend on everything that is outside its $\exists$ quantifier: $\epsilon, F, X,Y,d,C(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say $V$ can't depend on $F$? $V$ can and must depend on $F$. What wouldn't be allowed would be for $V$ to depend on $f_i\in F$, say. That $F$ is equicontinuous means that for the specific set of functions $F$, you can find a neighborhood on which each of the functions varies by less than $\epsilon$. Of course you can't find a neighborhood which would work no matter what the set $F$ is, otherwise you'd have a neighborhood $V$ on which every continuous function varies by at most $\epsilon$. That can't exist except in very simple topological spaces.

Your proof is correct.

Comment: It is a bit unclear. Being the pre-images of $f_j$, $V$ does depend on each $f_j$ as well, and it is ok as long as $V$ is *the same* for all $f$ in the test for $f(V)$.

Comment: I was making the analogy with the definition $\forall \epsilon: \exists \delta: \forall x : d() < \delta \implies d() < \epsilon$. Here, $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$. What's the difference here? Is the difference that $F$ is already introduced in the question statement?

Comment: @Math_QED There is no difference. Here $\delta$ may not depend on $x$ (which is a variable inside $\exists$ quantifier), but may depend on the function, the interval etc (which are constants). In your case, $V$ may not depend on $f$, which is a variable, but can depend on $F$, $f_j$, which are constants.